# Can calculated columns be exported, if site saved as a template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, site-template, list-template, template

I've created 10 different `Calculated columns` in various lists in SharePoint 2013 site. I am planning to save the site as a template for future reuse.

Please let me know is there any limitation for calculated column in `Save as template` feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation for `Calculated columns`. When you save the list as template which contains a `calculated column` it behaves normally. You will be able to save the list template and recreate a new list using that template. The newly created field also has the `Calculated column` with same formula.

Similarly when you save the site as template and reuse it, you will not face any issues with `Calculated columns`, you will get all your lists with all the calculated columns. I have done it many times.

Note: The limitation will be only for Lookup columns.

Comment: can you please educate on the limitation of lookup column, as i`ll be using it  pull data from source list and show as it as project dashboard list page.